# A compact notation for conditional set operations

Tags: lo.logic

I'm trying to write down the definition of the [type-3 grammar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chomsky_hierarchy#The_hierarchy) in pure mathematics and there is a rule $S \rightarrow \epsilon$ which can be in the ruleset under a certain condition. I've come up with this notation:
$$A=B\cup \begin{cases} C & \nexists x \in A : P(x) \\ \emptyset & otherwise \end{cases}\quad.$$
Of course, the claim $\forall x \in C: \neg P(x)$ is valid, but I don't know if the aforementioned notation is right and I don't like it anyway so I'm asking for a better (more compact) one.

### EDIT:

The more readable version:
$$A=B\cup \begin{cases} C & \nexists x \in B : P(x) \\ \emptyset & otherwise \end{cases}$$

Comment: If you want to define $A$ by this notation, then this notation suggests that the definition of $A$ depends on  what $A$ is, which is not a good idea.  Do you mean "there is no $x$ in $B$" in the first line of your alternative?

Comment: Actually, yes. It depends on what is in $B$ and not $C$, but with the supplemented proposition it should be ok. Nonetheless I'm going to do an edit.